# Android emulator (Nexus_5_API_23_x86) not starting

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm on Android Studio 1.3.2, with Android SDK 6 and Java SDK 8.
I'm trying to run a hello world app, but the emulator keeps loading forever. 
AVD: Nexus_5_API_23_x86 (I did install everything for 64bits, I'm not sure what this 'x86' is doing here).

Logcat (filtering errors only, and showing the final, as the full log is too large and Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post):

```
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-03 00:11:00.836      954-954/? E/Hyphenator﹕ error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-nn.pat.txt
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-nn.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-03 00:11:00.840      954-954/? E/Hyphenator﹕ error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-sa.pat.txt
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-sa.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-03 00:11:00.855      954-954/? E/Hyphenator﹕ error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-und-ethi.pat.txt
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-und-ethi.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-03 00:11:03.348      952-952/? E/installd﹕ eof
09-03 00:11:03.362      952-952/? E/installd﹕ failed to read size
09-03 00:11:08.364     938-1004/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-03 00:11:10.036    1192-1192/system_process E/art﹕ DexFile_getDexOptNeeded file '/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar' does not exist
09-03 00:12:01.555      947-947/? E/Netd﹕ cannot find interface dummy0
09-03 00:12:28.177    1192-1192/system_process E/System﹕ ******************************************
09-03 00:12:28.213    1192-1192/system_process E/System﹕ ************ Failure starting system services
    java.lang.RuntimeException: There must be one required installer
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getRequiredInstallerLPr(PackageManagerService.java:2416)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:2322)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:1763)
            at com.android.server.SystemServer.startBootstrapServices(SystemServer.java:366)
            at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:268)
            at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:168)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-03 00:12:28.220    1192-1192/system_process E/AndroidRuntime﹕ *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: There must be one required installer
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getRequiredInstallerLPr(PackageManagerService.java:2416)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.<init>(PackageManagerService.java:2322)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.main(PackageManagerService.java:1763)
            at com.android.server.SystemServer.startBootstrapServices(SystemServer.java:366)
            at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:268)
            at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:168)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-03 00:12:28.334    1192-1192/system_process E/AndroidRuntime﹕ Error reporting crash
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.app.IActivityManager.handleApplicationCrash(android.os.IBinder, android.app.ApplicationErrorReport$CrashInfo)' on a null object reference
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
            at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
09-03 00:12:28.494      952-952/? E/installd﹕ eof
09-03 00:12:28.497      952-952/? E/installd﹕ failed to read size
09-03 00:12:28.520      954-954/? E/Zygote﹕ Exit zygote because system server (1192) has terminated
09-03 00:12:34.568    1322-1322/? E/﹕ batterystats service unavailable!
09-03 00:12:34.569    1322-1322/? E/﹕ batterystats service unavailable!
09-03 00:12:34.587    1322-1322/? E/﹕ batterystats service unavailable!
09-03 00:12:34.587    1322-1322/? E/﹕ batterystats service unavailable!
09-03 00:12:34.946    1322-1322/? E/CameraService﹕ setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
09-03 00:12:40.307    1322-1355/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ no wake lock to update!
09-03 00:12:40.351    1322-1322/? E/audio_hw_generic﹕ Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
09-03 00:12:40.416    1322-1322/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ int android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or directory)
09-03 00:12:40.441    1322-1322/? E/SoundTriggerHwService﹕ couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
09-03 00:12:40.469    1322-1322/? E/RadioService﹕ couldn't load radio module radio.primary (No such file or directory)
09-03 00:12:42.590    1323-1323/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-03 00:12:42.590    1323-1323/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-03 00:12:44.713    1323-1323/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NanumGothic.ttf
09-03 00:12:44.715    1323-1323/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf
09-03 00:12:44.715    1323-1323/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/MTLmr3m.ttf
09-03 00:12:49.895    1323-1323/? E/EmojiFactory_jni﹕ Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found
09-03 00:13:12.073    1323-1323/? E/Hyphenator﹕ error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.pat.txt
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-03 00:13:12.117    1323-1323/? E/Hyphenator﹕ error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-eu.pat.txt
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-eu.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-03 00:13:12.120    1323-1323/? E/Hyphenator﹕ error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-hu.pat.txt
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-hu.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-03 00:13:12.136    1323-1323/? E/Hyphenator﹕ error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-hy.pat.txt
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-hy.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-03 00:13:12.140    1323-1323/? E/Hyphenator﹕ error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-nb.pat.txt
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-nb.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-03 00:13:12.174    1323-1323/? E/Hyphenator﹕ error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-nn.pat.txt
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-nn.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-03 00:13:12.178    1323-1323/? E/Hyphenator﹕ error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-sa.pat.txt
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-sa.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-03 00:13:12.181    1323-1323/? E/Hyphenator﹕ error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-und-ethi.pat.txt
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-und-ethi.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.<init>(IoUtils.java:207)
            at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
            at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-03 00:13:13.989      952-952/? E/installd﹕ eof
09-03 00:13:13.990      952-952/? E/installd﹕ failed to read size
09-03 00:13:15.976     938-1004/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-03 00:13:16.771    1431-1431/system_process E/art﹕ DexFile_getDexOptNeeded file '/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar' does not exist
09-03 00:13:26.923    1431-1431/system_process A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 2 in tid 1431 (system_server)
09-03 00:13:27.337      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-03 00:13:27.337      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:6.0/MRA44C/2166767:eng/test-keys'
09-03 00:13:27.338      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '0'
09-03 00:13:27.338      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ ABI: 'x86'
09-03 00:13:27.340      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ pid: 1431, tid: 1431, name: system_server  >>> system_server <<<
09-03 00:13:27.340      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 2 (TRAP_TRACE), fault addr 0x597
09-03 00:13:27.556      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ eax ce1ff1ac  ebx 0000003f  ecx 00000032  edx 0000000d
09-03 00:13:27.556      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ esi bfd991e0  edi ad6fad40
09-03 00:13:27.557      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000007  xss 0000007b
09-03 00:13:27.557      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ eip b6726804  ebp ab7b2f00  esp bfd991c0  flags 50ec5387
09-03 00:13:27.601      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
09-03 00:13:27.602      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ #00 pc 0002d804  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
09-03 00:13:27.602      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ #01 pc 5fc19070  <unknown>
09-03 00:13:32.253      948-948/? A/DEBUG﹕ Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_00
09-03 00:13:33.477      952-952/? E/installd﹕ eof
09-03 00:13:33.480      952-952/? E/installd﹕ failed to read size
09-03 00:13:33.600    1323-1323/? E/Zygote﹕ Exit zygote because system server (1431) has terminated
09-03 00:13:39.580    1511-1511/? E/﹕ batterystats service unavailable!
09-03 00:13:39.584    1511-1511/? E/﹕ batterystats service unavailable!
09-03 00:13:39.606    1511-1511/? E/﹕ batterystats service unavailable!
09-03 00:13:39.606    1511-1511/? E/﹕ batterystats service unavailable!
09-03 00:13:40.187    1511-1511/? E/CameraService﹕ setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
09-03 00:13:45.553    1511-1542/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ no wake lock to update!
09-03 00:13:45.577    1511-1511/? E/audio_hw_generic﹕ Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
09-03 00:13:45.640    1511-1511/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ int android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or directory)
09-03 00:13:45.670    1511-1511/? E/SoundTriggerHwService﹕ couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
09-03 00:13:45.673    1511-1511/? E/RadioService﹕ couldn't load radio module radio.primary (No such file or directory)
09-03 00:13:47.549    1512-1512/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-03 00:13:47.549    1512-1512/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-03 00:13:49.637    1512-1512/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NanumGothic.ttf
09-03 00:13:49.638    1512-1512/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf
09-03 00:13:49.639    1512-1512/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/MTLmr3m.ttf
09-03 00:13:54.667    1512-1512/? E/EmojiFactory_jni﹕ Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found
```

I'm on a Intel i3 with 4GB RAM (1GB free)

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: If your PC is running on an AMD Processor, you should use the ARM image for the android emulator, because the x86 images works for the Intel processors. The x86 android images run faster than the ARM images, even without using the HAXM technology, but requieres your pc to have an intel processor.

Comment: @IvanVerges its Intel i3

Comment: In that case, try to configure the HAXM, and if you're able, create an older emulated device, for example, a Nexus 4 with Kitkat, with the x86 Image. I'll try to run a device with your settings and see what happens.

Comment: I had the HAXM installed. It worked after I open only the AndroidStudio and emulator (with little more then 1gb memory free), and used the AVD with 512MB.

Answer (score 1):

Try this configuration, it works like a charm.

[image]

[image]

NOTE1: I'm working on a Lenovo ThinkPad with an Intel i3 processor running at 2.10GHz, 8GB of RAM Memory and Windows 8.1.

NOTE2: I had to install the HAXM from the SDK Folder "\SDK\extras\Intel\"

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I open only the AndroidStudio and emulator (with little more then 1gb memory free), and used the AVD with 512MB.