# how to solve unfortunately myapp has stopped? [SOLVED]

Tags: java, android, error-handling

In Android Studio I successfully generate my signed apk then I download my apk in Android phone and in Android emulator then it shows unfortunately myapp has stopped. How to solve this problem???

Here is logcat error report------------>

```html
    05-01 14:03:13.824 1267-1267/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-as.hyb
         java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-as.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
             at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
             at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
             at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:722)
          Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
             at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
             at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247) 
             at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118) 
             at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:722) 
    05-01 14:03:13.824 1267-1267/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-bn.hyb
         java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-bn.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
             at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
             at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
             at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:722)
          Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
             at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
             at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247) 
             at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118) 
             at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:722) 
    05-01 14:03:13.824 1267-1267/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-cy.hyb
         java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-cy.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
             at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
             at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
             at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:722)
          Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
             at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
             at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247) 
             at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118) 
             at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:722) 
    05-01 14:03:13.825 1267-1267/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-da.hyb
         java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-da.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
             at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
             at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
             at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:722)
          Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
             at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
             at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247) 
             at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118) 
             at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206) 
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:722) 
    05-01 14:03:13.825 1267-1267/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-de-1901.hyb
         java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-de-1901.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
             at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
             at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
             at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:722)
```

so anyone can help me in this problem any suggestion or any other idea so tell me so thats help me and i solved it.

Comment: It looks as if it could be a memory issue or AVD configuration issue. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381154/android-emulator-nexus-5-api-23-x86-not-starting

Comment: no not avd problem

Comment: after my apk successfully generate i download my app then i see one dialog box come and show unfortunately myapp has stopped so how to solve this error???

Comment: You need to provide more information relating to your application. What is your app trying to achieve? Do you have any code examples that could provide more context.

Comment: yes i know i need to provide more information but in stackoverflow before this i try to send more information but in stackoverflow shows you add lots of words remove this so that is the i cut lots of information.

Comment: can we connect in gmail so i send you more information

Comment: If you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score -1):

I think issue is related to memory leak or less heap memory size so ill suggest
Try to use **multiDexEnabled true** in your app build.gradle file 
something like

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0.0.0.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

     dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

and In you AndroidManifiest.xml inside application tag **android:largeHeap="true"**

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Please provide more information about issue

Comment: thank you but in i think my app is crash so it works or not??

Comment: sushant can you give me your email id so give you more information because i cant send more information here shows you add lots of words remove some words so if you send your email id so i easily send my more information.

Comment: i cant share my email id with u but ................i can help u here !! 1. just comment code that you perform file oprations ....File Object where u use ,dont use that   2. Check app with lower version/higher version of android let me know if work on any of version 3. Go to file-> Invalidate Cache and Restart Studio

Comment: 4.Check Permission   READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in Manifest file And also runtime permission

Comment: hello sushant are you here

Comment: sushant i have logcat error report but i cant send logcat error report because in stackoverflow show its lots of words so that is the reason i give my email id please contact me.

Comment: no read permission and not external storage and no runtime permission how to add this permissions

Comment: no read permission and not external storage and no runtime permission how to add this permissions

Comment: you need to read about android permission https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html    read this carefully

Comment: thank you for giving me this link but tell me one think i add this permission so my app is open in every android emulator and in every android phones

Comment: yes but i am still confused is there issue in only in permission or  any other   issue until you show me your code

Comment: okayyy,but i know you say me that thing and i already try to send my codes in stackoverflow but it shows ERROR OCCURED:you use 1000000000000 words please remove it yes i remove then it again show you use 2345 word please more again and again i add and remove 20 times i add and remove the codes but i cant send codes so can you please provide me your email id so i easily contact with you or if you hesitate to send your email id so i send my email id please try to understand my problem its very so that reason i say you give me your email address